# Deployment of VSTO plugin via Advanced Installer

Tags: installation, vsto, outlook-addin, advanced-installer

I am attempting to create an install package for a VSTO add-in I've written for Microsoft Outlook 2010 and 2013. I wish for it to be simple to upgrade this plugin as it will be deployed to a great many clients.

I am however encountering a problem after deployment of this add-in. It shows up in Add/remove programs as two programs, the install package I create and the VSTO add-in after Outlook has run the .vsto-file. This means that in the event that the user would want to uninstall the add-in he or she will have to uninstall two applications. The same goes for upgrading I figure.

Any ideas here guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved on the [Advanced Installer forums](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20441#p50212). If you don't have the latest edition of Advanced Installer you can manually fix the registry entries, as detailed in the forums post.

Also, it is highly recommended you have your entire MSI signed with a valid digital certificate when deploying it to your users.